# Load custom Android 11 kernel to AVD/emulator

Tags: android, kernel, emulation, android-source, android-virtual-device

I want to be able to build a custom kernel and run it on an Android Virtual Device (AVD). I have attempted the following instructions but it results in a boot loop. I followed instructions here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels to download Android kernel source.

Synced and built with

```
repo init -b common-android-mainline && repo sync
repo sync
BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.x86_64 build/build.sh
```

Ran the emulator with a Pixel 4, API 30, ABI x86_64 AVD

```
emulator @Pixel_4_API_30 -kernel out/android-mainline/dist/bzImage -show-kernel -verbose
```

These are some lines that occur before the device reboots:

```
android::init::BlockDevInitializer::InitDevices(std::set<std::string>): partition(s) not found in /sys, waiting for their uevent(s): metadata, super, vbmeta
[   10.888602] init: Wait for partitions returned after 10010ms
[   10.889489] init: bool android::init::BlockDevInitializer::InitDevices(std::set<std::string>): partition(s) not found after polling timeout: metadata, super, vbmeta
[   10.891648] init: Failed to mount required partitions early ...
[   10.892517] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue. If so, could you please guide me as I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I also have the same issue. It feels like nobody knows how to solve this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Kernel must match virtual_device, virtual device related modules will be packaged into ramdisk, so your ramdisk must also be updated

Below is the kernel compile product, all ko need to be synchronized to ramdisk

abi.prop                   goldfish_pipe.ko            modules.builtin           snd-hda-codec.ko          usbip-core.ko             virtio_pmem.ko
ac97_bus.ko                goldfish_sync.ko            modules.builtin.modinfo   snd-hda-codec-realtek.ko  vcan.ko                   virtio-rng.ko
btintel.ko                 gs_usb.ko                   modules.load              snd-hda-core.ko           vendor_boot.modules.load  virtio_snd.ko
btrtl.ko                   hci_vhci.ko                 modules-only.symvers      snd-hda-intel.ko          vhci-hcd.ko               virt_wifi.ko
btusb.ko                   initramfs.img               modules.order             snd-intel8x0.ko           virtio_balloon.ko         virt_wifi_sim.ko
bzImage                    kernel-headers.tar.gz       Module.symvers            snd-intel-dspcfg.ko       virtio_blk.ko             vmlinux
cfg80211.ko                kernel-uapi-headers.tar.gz  nd_virtio.ko              system_heap.ko            virtio_console.ko         vmlinux.o
defconfig                  ledtrig-audio.ko            net_failover.ko           System.map                virtio_dma_buf.ko         vmlinux.symvers
dummy-cpufreq.ko           lzo.ko                      psmouse.ko                test_mapping_files.txt    virtio-gpu.ko             vmw_vsock_virtio_transport.ko
failover.ko                lzo-rle.ko                  pulse8-cec.ko             test_mappings.zip         virtio_input.ko           zram.ko
gnss-cmdline.ko            mac80211_hwsim.ko           rtc-test.ko               test_meminit.ko           virtio_mem.ko             zsmalloc.ko
gnss-serial.ko             mac80211.ko                 slcan.ko                  test_stackinit.ko         virtio_mmio.ko
goldfish_address_space.ko  Makefile                    snd-ac97-codec.ko         tpm.ko                    virtio_net.ko
goldfish_battery.ko        md-mod.ko                   snd-hda-codec-generic.ko  tpm_vtpm_proxy.ko         virtio_pci.ko

you need:
cp dist/* aosp/kernel/prebuilts/common-modules/virtual-device/5.10/x86-64/